# run program multiple times using one line shell command

Tags: command-line, shell

I have the following gifs on my linux system:

```
$ find . -name *.gif
./gifs/02.gif17.gif
./gifs/fit_logo_en.gif
./gifs/halloween_eyes_63.gif
./gifs/importing-pcs.gif
./gifs/portal.gif
./gifs/Sunflower_as_gif_small.gif
./gifs/weird.gif
./gifs2/00p5dr69.gif
./gifs2/iss013e48788.gif
...and so on
```

What I have written is a program that converts GIF files to BMP with the following interface:

./gif2bmp -i inputfile -o outputfile

My question is, is it possible to write a one line command using xargs, awk, find etc. to run my program once for each one of these files? Or do I have to write a shell script with a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that kind of work, it may be worth looking at `find` man page, especially the `-exec` option.

You can write something along the line of:

```
find . -name *.gif -exec gif2bmp -i {} -o {}.bmp \;
```

You can play with combinations of`dirname` and `basename` to obtain better naming for the output file, though in this case, I would prefer to use a shell `for` loop, something like:

```
for i in `find . -name "*.gif"`; do
  DIR=`dirname $i`
  NAME=`basename $i .gif`
  gif2bmp -i $i -o ${DIR}/${NAME}.bmp
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I ended up using the following command:

find . -name *.gif -exec ./convert -i {} -o {}.bmp \;

The only problem with this is that my output file have extension .bmp.gif, but at least it works :)

Comment: Good one-liner tonio. The .gif.bmp issue is why I'll usually go for the extra lines to pull out the base filename and change the extension.

Comment: @teehoo: the answer to the suffix problem is to write a shell script to cover the converter:  `exec ./gif2bmp -i "$1" -o "${1%.gif}.bmp"`.  You then run that from `find`:  `find . -name '*.gif' -exec ./wrapper {} \;`.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel ./gif2bmp -i {} -o {.}.bmp ::: *.gif
```

The added benefit is that it will run one job for each cpu core in parallel.

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html). You command line with love you for it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info - it's not a standard utility on a default Debian Jessie install though :(

Comment: See if your excuse is covered on http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html